# Is it possible to create Services with VS2017 Community?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, service, windows-services

Is it possible to create a Windows Service with Visual Studio 2017 Community?
[I followed this guide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/816169/how-to-create-a-setup-project-for-a-windows-service-application-in-vis), however, it recommends VS2008. I also read somewhere that you can only create services with enterprise version.

I was able to complete every step in the guide and the installation was even successful but the service doesn't appear amongst the services.

Is the problem with Visual Studio or is there a better/more recent guide?

Comment: Yes, you can. It's not clear whether your problem is with the service or your installer, have you checked the event viewer "System" logs for any errors raised by the service and "Application" logs for any thing raised by the installer? And have you tried rebooting to see if the service appears in the SCM? What are you using for your setup project BTW, the deployment project extension for VS2017?

Comment: @stuartd I restarted the computer, nothing. I use [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) installer extension. The system log has 3 errors: 2xDistributedCOM and 1xService Control Manager. This Date and Time seem to be the time when I tried to install the service but I can't say for sure.

Comment: What's the SCM error?

Comment: @stuartd Error message: "The CldFlt service failed to start due to the following error: 
The request is not supported." There are multiple entries just like this.

Comment: I take it that's [not the name of your service](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29044412/Windows-10-The-CldFlt-service-failed-to-start-due-to-the-following-error.html).

Comment: Do you need an installer, i.e. are you distributing the service? I have to say here that I have always used the excellent [Topshelf library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Topshelf/) for WIndows Services to avoid the pain of "raw" service development, so I probably can't help anyway.

Comment: @stuartd Eventually I will distribute but for now, I just want it to work. I'll give Topshelf a try.